# mvc passing info from view(input type) to controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am new on mvc and i have this code on my view

```
 $('#btnSearch').click(function(){

    var idnumber = $('#txtIDNumber').val();
        var startdate = $('#txtStartDate').val();
        var enddate = $('#txtEndDate').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/MyController/GetUserInput',
            data: {'id' : idnumber,'start date':startdate,'end date':enddate},
            type:"post",
            cache:false,
            success: function(){
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("error");
            }

        });
    });
```

I would like to pass this info from my input to my contoller. How do i go about doing this, ive been googling but the answers i find are not helping. Whats wrong with my code?
This is my controller

```
 public ActionResult GetUserInput(Mymodel model )
    {

        var idnumber = model.ID_Number;
        var startdate = model.Start_Date;
        var enddate = model.End_Date;



        return View("Index");
    }
```

please help

Comment: try adding   [httppost] above your action

Comment: i have that, its still not working

Comment: alright your model properties are not matching with 
data: {'id' : idnumber,'start date':startdate,'end date':enddate},


try matching them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out a solution, the problem was with my ajax. this is how its supposed to be:

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {

        var idnumber = $('#txtIDNumber').val();
        var startdate = $('#txtStartDate').val();
        var enddate = $('#txtEndDate').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Mycontroller/GetUserInput',
            data: { ID_Number: idnumber, Start_Date: startdate, End_Date: enddate },
            type: "post",
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }

        });
    });
```

and the code on mycontoller stays the same. Im hoping this will help someone else. Thank you!